# Как привязать Frame(и виджет в нём) в tkinter к краю экрана?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

f_top = tk.Frame(root)
f_intop = tk.Frame(f_top)
tool_bar = tk.Label(f_intop, bg='gray', text="toolbar")
l1 = tk.Label(f_top, bg='yellow', text="yellow one")
l2 = tk.Label(f_top, bg='green', text="green one")

f_top.pack()
f_intop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
l1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
l2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tool_bar.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Вот, к примеру, у меня есть такой код. В нём я хочу привязать Label tool_bar к левому краю экрана, но при изменении размера окна, он остаётся на своём месте. Как это сделать?
[image: начальное состояние]
[image: состояние при изменении размеров окна]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можете использовать [`anchor`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack-method) для прикрепления объекта к области

P.s. не совсем понял зачем вы фрейм создаете во фрейме если так и надо то тут уже могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы :)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

f_top = tk.Frame(root)
f_intop = tk.Frame(root)
tool_bar = tk.Label(f_intop, bg='gray', text="toolbar")
l1 = tk.Label(f_top, bg='yellow', text="yellow one")
l2 = tk.Label(f_top, bg='green', text="green one")

l1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
l2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tool_bar.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

f_intop.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.NE)
f_top.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]